# dynamic template: store object as a plain string

Tags: elasticsearch

Assumed that the following document will be inserted into Elasticsearch.

```
{
    "message": "hello",
    "request": {
        "body": {
            "data": "hi",
            "some_what_dynamic": {
                "nested": {
                    "not_ending": 10000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given that field `request.body` is dynamic object which has nested objects and/or fields inside, I want to store the whole `request.body` as a `string` and I don't want Elasticsearch to create new field for properties inside `request.body` object.

How can I define mapping to achieve this?

Here's current dynamic_templates definition:

```
{
    "template": "logstash-*",
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "message_field": {
                        "path_match": "message",
                        "mapping": {
                            "norms": false,
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "string"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "string_fields": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "norms": false,
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "match": "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "body_fields": {
                        "match": "body",
                        "mapping": {
                            "norms": false,
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "object"
                    }
                }
            ],
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to insert document, I got `MapperParsingException` with message `Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at...`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to wrap everything in the body element in double quotes? Something like this might work (javascript)?

```
a={
    "message": "hello",
    "request": {
        "body": {
            "data": "hi",
            "some_what_dynamic": {
                "nested": {
                    "not_ending": 10000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}; 
a.request.body = JSON.stringify(a.request.body);
```